# Second html canvas is not rendering

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm following a tutorial right now where you're working with canvas, and the tutorial guy is drawing on the canvas every time while I want to keep every tutorial on the same page, hence getting a canvas with the code from one episode, below it another canvas with the code for the 2nd tutorial. Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>

</html>



window.onload = function () {
    /** @type {CanvasRenderingContext2D} */
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight / 2;

    context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);


    for (var index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height);
        context.lineTo(Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height);
        context.strokeStyle = "#FFFF00";
        context.stroke();
    }

    var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
    var context2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
    var width2 = canvas2.width = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var height2 = canvas2.height = window.innerHeight / 2;
    context2.translate(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
    context2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    for (var angle = 0; angle < Math.PI * 2; angle += .01) {
        console.log(Math.sin(angle));
        var x = angle * 200;
        var y = Math.sin(angle) * 200;
        context2.fillStyle = "green"
        context2.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5)
    }
}
```

On the first canvas I draw random lines, on the 2nd canvas a sine wave should be displayed (made by small rectangles), but it isn't rendering while I have no errors and the values are correct when i console log them. I can't seem to find an answer in MDN, not W3

Answer (score 0):

You are translating the 2nd canvas which causes all of the following draws to be rendered outside of the canvas coordinates. Remove the translate and everything should be fine.

P.S. You are clearing the second canvas with the dimensions of the first one, which is likely to cause issues. In general, naming variables as `width1`, leads to errors. Rename them / move to a function to avoid such errors in the future.